# Alarm fires on "sleeping" Android device

Tags: android

I am writing an Android AppWidget that needs to be updated frequently (yes, I know, shouldn't do that, whatever...). I would like it to be updated only if it is visible, but annoyingly there seems to be nothing similar to `WallpaperService.Engine.onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible)`.

The suggested approach here is to set up an alarm with `AlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, firstShot, interval, pendingIntent)` that triggers the update every `interval` milliseconds. This would at least not wake the device when it is asleep.

That's just what I did. My `PendingIntent` looks like this:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(context, CountdownWidgetService.class);
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

The `CountdownWidgetService` logs a message every time it is triggered by the alarm. The log message shows up even when the device should be asleep - but that's just what I thought was not supposed to happen. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some other app you have is waking up the device, and your alarm gets executed with it. If you use `AlarmManager.RTC` that means: 'execute if the device is awake or wait until it is awake and execute then'. Check logcat to see what is happening and use this command to see what other alarms are registered:

```
adb shell dumpsys alarm
```

Comment: @Oderik You probably wanted to add this as a comment, not an edit to my post. Add it below if you want to: EDIT: Patience was the key: The device needs some time to actually fall asleep after the screen goes off (and ADB is disconnected). After that, the alarm doesn't fire.

Thanks for the advice that lead to the right investigation. Seeing how often the device wakes up reminds me of fresh parents. ;)

Comment: No, I did want to edit the answer because it does not yet include the solution: Android takes some time before actually going to sleep. But I guess others will find it in the comments just as well. Thanks, again!

Comment: It showed up as an edit to my answer. BTW, the reason it 'takes some time' to go to sleep is that some app is holding a wake lock. Android by default goes to sleep as soon as the screen is off. Apps can request it to stay awake until they finish their processing, etc. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html